# Why is it not possible to store multiple byte characters in a single byte character set system?

Tags: python, encoding

I could see a Python string (not unicode string i.e u'') input `\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87` which is `中文` changing to `\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\xbf\xbf` after storing it in a Oracle Table whose column is a CLOB (VARCHAR) using `WE8MSWIN1252` Character Set and retrieving it in Python using a Web Framework. I am trying to troubleshoot and understand as to what happens in low level terms.

**Why would database change my input - I thought what goes in also comes out?**

I am told, "it is because WE8MSWIN1252 is a single byte system and it doesn't support multibyte encodings". This is a bit high-level explanation for me at the moment. Multibyte is still 3 bytes. So why can't the `WE8MSWIN1252` system break it down into 3 different bytes say `\xe6,\x96 and \x87` store it and leave it to the end user to interpret it?

What does it mean to say single byte encoding can't accommodate multiple byte systems? What is it that I am missing in my understanding? Its all 1's and 0's. We store bits and not Unicode etc - that is a higher level of abstraction?

Comment: If the database is capable of performing character set conversions, it must guarantee that the characters going in belong to the character set you claim. But `\x96` and `\xe7` [appear to be valid characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout) so the problem must lie in some subtle interaction.

Comment: _(96) ‡(87) . Do you agree that it shouldn't change the input per that logic ? Let the Charset assume its something else . I have no issue since I can enforce a UTF-8 when I render it .  I can see that the first character is retained perfectly and hence was expecting the second one to do the same . I was atleast hoping that I could read the stream and enforce a utf-8 to make it work ! I need to learn this a bit more deeply , but atleast can you clarify if you think that you agree this should no have happened purely on logical basis and need more research ? Its more to understand all this.

Comment: The DB can't just leave things alone since it guarantees the ability to do character set conversions. In fact it may be doing a conversion both on the way in and the way out and using some unrelated character set for internal storage, for consistency. Whether it should or should not work in this particular case is irrelevant, since abarnert has provided an example where it's guaranteed to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of encoded strings is that you *aren't* just storing bits, you're storing *strings*. Oracle's [Choosing a character set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10749/ch2charset.htm) documentation explains exactly what this means, in terms of an Oracle database.

A single-byte encoding only knows how to represent (at most) 256 different characters. If you give it a different character, it can't represent that. What should it do instead?

What you're suggesting is that it should take the representation in some *other* encoding, and just pretend the bytes are characters in its own encoding. Not only does that not make sense conceptually, it doesn't work practically—in fact, that's exactly what mojibake is.

To take your concrete example, you have a WE8MSWIN1252 (roughly the same encoding Python calls cp1252) string column. You want to store the string `'中文'`. There is no cp1252 for that, but there is a UTF-8 for it, and it's `'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'`.

So, what if you just stored the UTF-8 bytes *as if* they were cp1252 characters? Well, it depends on how code page 1252 is defined by your database. Those last two bytes were not valid characters in the original code page 1252, but current Windows code page 1252 does map them to characters. So, if the database goes by the IBM rules it should either give you an error, or replace the bytes with the "invalid character" representation (at least for encodings that have such a thing);* if it tries to emulate Windows, it should allow it.**

To avoid that question, let's make it simpler: What if you picked a full 256-character Latin-1-based encoding? That would trick it into allowing you to store the data. And then you'd be storing the string `'ä¸­æ'` or `'ä¸\xadæ–‡'` or something similar. That doesn't seem very useful. You could write an application where doing so would make sense (because you know you're going to recode through Latin-1 mojibake to UTF-8 to the real string on every side), but in that case, why are you using a string in the first place? Just use a binary column, and skip the whole Latin-1 part, and it's up to the application to know that the binary data means UTF-8, rather than being up to the application to know that what looks like Latin-1 has to be recoded to be useful as UTF-8.

Or, even simpler, just use a UTF-8 column, or stop trying to store east-Asian text in a cp1252 columns…

---

<sub>* See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10749/ch2charset.htm) for how Oracle interprets replacement characters, which is a little more complicated than you might expect, and not the same as Python.</sub>

<sub>** The fact that your database calls the encoding `WE8MSWIN1252` seems to imply that it *should* be using the Windows definition; the fact that it's converting them to 0xBF implies that it isn't doing so. It's possible that this is reasonable because by "MSWIN" they mean "MS Windows 3.1" or, hell, even "MS Windows 1.0", but I really have no idea. At any rate, as the next paragraph explains, it doesn't really matter. If you want to see what happens with characters that shouldn't be legal under any meaning of "code page 1252", see try `'東京'`, which is `'\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe4\xba\xac'` in UTF-8, and 0x9D is intentionally left blank in cp1252.</sub>

Comment: But [`\x96` *is* a valid character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout). `'\x96'.decode('cp1252')` returns `u'\u2013'` and it works the other way too. P.S. Not that I disagree that lying to the DB is a bad idea, it just doesn't explain the literal example.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks; please look over the new version. I thought about using an example that _does_ give an error (IIRC, the kanji for Tokyo did?), but I think it's better to just sidestep that issue. What do you think?

Comment: Everything you say makes sense. I wish I could find the exact character table that Oracle assumes for `WE8MSWIN1252` but my web search fails me, and I don't have access to Oracle to see for myself.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, I can't find it either. Anyway, I added the Tokyo example to the footnotes just in case…

Comment: @MarkRansom: To make things even more fun, I found some (possibly pirated, so I won't link them…) docs where none of the images load, but they seem to imply that WE8MSWIN1252 is one of the code pages that was updated to include the Euro symbol, which makes it less likely that my guess was right…

Comment: Appreciate in depth reply . In the first sentence when you say "strings" do you mean that database promises a string to be stored for retrieval and not the literal bit by bit of what you input ? Assume I store a into a UTF-16 system and it stores 2 bytes and that is because operations like "like" operator rely heavily on encoding and not informing the encoding to DB means we can't make sense of the information - just like a BLOB - which obviously is not the purpose of CLOB or VARCHAR ? I.e DB has to make sense of the data as much as the end user ? Unlike Blob which is just for end user ?

Comment: @Nishant: Yeah, I think that's a reasonable way to put it, and using a non-ASCII-compatible character set like UTF-16 makes the example a lot clearer.